# Add css style to django ckeditor

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

I'm using django ckeditor

I can add and edit HTML tags, but can't add CSS styles
[image]

Is there any way to add CSS style to the content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `'allowedContent': True` to your `CKEDITOR_CONFIGS`, in the `settings.py` file:

```py
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        # ... your default config...
        'allowedContent': True
    }
}
```

You can see a full config example in the docs: https://django-ckeditor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#example-ckeditor-configuration

Comment: That's what I need!. Thank you so much!